# grails metaprogramming

Tags: grails, groovy, metaprogramming

My understanding is that there are two obvious places in a Grails app where one can do meta-programming:

1. The `init` closure of `Bootstrap.groovy`
2. The `doWithDynamicMethods` closure of a plugin

The meta-programming I'm referring to here should be visible throughout the application, typical examples include adding (or replacing) methods of 3rd party classes.

```
String.metaClass.myCustomMethod = { /* implementation omitted */ }
```

The disadvantage of (1), is that the metaprogramming won't be applied when the application is dynamically reloaded. The disadvantage of (2) is that I need to create and maintain an entire plugin just for the sake of a little metaprogramming.

Is there a better place to do this kind of metaprogramming?

### Update

Following Ted's suggestion below, I added the following class to `src/groovy`

```
package groovy.runtime.metaclass.java.lang

/**
 * Adds custom methods to the String class
 */
class StringMetaClass extends DelegatingMetaClass {

    StringMetaClass(MetaClass meta) {
        super(meta)
    }

    Object invokeMethod(Object object, String method, Object[] arguments) {
        if (method == 'hasGroovy') {
            object ==~ /.*[Gg]roovy.*/
        } else {
            super.invokeMethod object, method, arguments
        }
    }
}
```

Then restarted the app and ran the following code in the Grails console:

```
assert 'mrhaki loves Groovy'.hasGroovy()
```

I got the following exception

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
java.lang.String.hasGroovy() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there a reason this doesn't work in a Grails app?

Comment: It's a shame there isn't a simple answer for this...

Comment: is (1) still the case? i just tried it (only a simple example) and all seems ok (i can change the controller and the bootstrap itself and changes are hot-recompiled).

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Delegating MetaClass](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+the+Delegating+Meta+Class), it's part of groovy and makes your metaclass changes part of the metaclass that's used on every instance of that class right from the start.  It operates on a simple convention and even works outside of grails.

Comment: My question is about where in a Grails app should I apply metaprogramming, not how to do the metaprogramming itself.

Comment: Right, I understand that.  That's why I'm suggesting that the place that you should do it is within a convention named class that makes your changes/additions available throughout the grails application and don't suffer from the problems of putting it in BootStrap, or some other "init" method that might or might not have been called by the time you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your use case, [Groovy AST transformations](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Building+AST+Guide) are a third option. AST transformation are modifications of the bytecode at compile time. They are available since Groovy 1.6 and have been improved a lot in Groovy 1.7. Esp. ASTBuilder is a very elegant way.

Be aware that using AST within Grails might require some modifications to the build. The classes performing the AST must be compiled before the classes that are subject to AST. This could be easily done by hooking into the "CompileStart" event in scripts/_Events.groovy and precompile the Transformation first.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but if I just want to add a few methods to a class, this sounds like overkill.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DelegatingMetaClass solution, but it needs to be packaged in a JAR file and then added to the lib directory.

Create a new directory with the following Gradle build file:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
repositories.mavenCentral()
dependencies { groovy: 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:1.8.6' }
```

In the src/main/groovy directory you can place the StringMetaClass source code. With $ gradle jar you can create a JAR file and then copy it to the lib directory of your Grails application.

Comment: I literally just want to add a single method to the `String` class, so this seems like overkill. I'll probably just add it as a static method to my own `StringUtils` class, even though I'd prefer to have it as an instance method of `String`. As far as I can tell, there doesn't seem to be any simple reliable method of doing metaprogramming in a Grails app which is surprising.

Comment: presumably I don't have to use Gradle, e.g. I could also use Maven to create the JAR?